# Java Long parselong throwing Number Format exception

Tags: java, long-integer

I have a simple code first I use this

```
Long.parseLong(4250120140405520712)
```

And it works but when I do this

```
Long.parseLong(42501201404055207123)
```

It fails. Adding an extra digit makes it throw a Number Format Exception. Can someone please explain

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're parsing `String`s into `long`s:

The first one works because the number 4250120140405520712 (19 digits) is less than the maximum possible long value, [`Long.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE), `9223372036854775807L`.

The second one fails because it's 20 digits long, bigger than `9223372036854775807L`.

Comment: and we can use BigInteger to represent the second number

Answer (score 1):

`long` variables can only hold a maximum of 9223372036854775807 see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) for more information.
The reason the second one doesn't work is that you have exceeded the limit so the number format exception is shown.